# Post one feed item to multiple friends' feeds

Tags: facebook, post, feed, facebook-opengraph

I'd like to post a feed item to my Profile Time Line and my friend's Profile Time Line.  The goal is to share comments similar to what you can get when you share a posted story to another friend.  I get back a post_id when I post a new feed item -- is it possible to "cross post" the same post to my wall?

[EDITED to clarify Facebook terminology]

Answer (score 0):

When you post on your user's wall, that same story will automatically appear on friends of that user's walls too if their privacy settings don't get in the way.  So the one post will carry the same comments on it regardless of if they entered them from their friends wall, or their own wall.

Comment: A believe you are confusing the the home page with a user's timeline.

Comment: If wall == homepage and timeline == feed, then I think we're talking the same thing.

Comment: You can tag the friend in your post, that should get it displayed on the other person's timeline.

Comment: Can you supply specific code to do this?  I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please add that code to your question and we'll help you debug it.

Comment: No sorry, it didn't answer the question.  The goal is to cross-post, not post one item as a work around.  Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand.  Are you asking for a new feature to be added to Facebook to be able to post the same post in two places, or are you asking for how to accomplish your task of getting the comments to appear in one place?